# pointCloud2 to pcl::pointcloud conversion

Tags: pcl, velodyne, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using velodyne VLP16. The information I am getting from it is "unordered" pointCloud2. I am having a trouble to translate it to pcl::pointcloud. According to the code provided online [here] (https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/colors.cc). I can simply get the x,y, and z value of the point from pointCloud2 by using a pcl function **without giving the function any information regarding the sensor** I am using(layer no. etc). Why is this the case?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246281/pointcloud2-to-pcl::pointcloud-conversion/) by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2016-10-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have figured it out thanks to joq's comment. In the /velodyne/velodyne_pointcloud/include/velodyne_pointcloud there is a header file point_types.h. If you are writing a subscribe for velodyne_point you will need to include this header file so pcl_converter is able to interpret the topic and convert is to pcl::pointcloud.  The callback function of the subscriber will do the conversion on the fly as it receives velodyne_point.

---

Originally posted by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) with karma: 54 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code you mention does use a PCL point cloud. The [for loop](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/colors.cc#L75) iterates over the entire cloud. Each `inMsg->points[i]` object contains `x`, `y`, `z`, and `ring`, as shown.

I am not yet sure what else you are asking.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) on 2016-10-24**:
Sir, from your comments on the two questions I posted, I am able to clarify my question. In the color.cc The node subscribes to /velodyne_points which is pointCloud2. I can't find the place where this topic is translated to a pcl point cloud.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-10-24**:
That happens under the covers using [pcl_conversions](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_conversions). I'm not sure exactly how that works.

**Comment by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) on 2016-10-25**:
Understood. I will look into it and let you know if I figure it out

**Comment by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) on 2016-10-30**:
I have other questions. x,y,z reading is in meter right? Is the origin the Velodyne sensor?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-10-31**:
Yes, the ROS standard is for *all* distances to be in meters. The origin is the TF frame named in the message header's `frame_id`. By default that is the `velodyne` frame.